# vertices that are not affected by subdivision surface modifier

Tags: modeling, vertices, subdivision-surface

[image]

[image]

I'm a beginner and i'm trying to modelise a body. I start by the base very low poly but then when i applied the subdivision surface modifier it seems to doesn't apply to the vertices in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try recalculating normals, or flipping the 'not working' ones